# The working of a MFRC522 and its Interface protocols?

Tags: i2c, spi, uart, rfid

I've actually messed up and posted into the stackoverflow site, even though I'm probably not meant to. I've been given [this](https://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MFRC522.pdf) datasheet, but even though it does explain somewhat how each host interfaces works, it does not fully answer the questions I have at the moment and I probably don't even know what I'm doing in the first place, hence I'm giving this question another shot in the right place.

I've enrolled recently into a programming course, and one of the subject seems to be embedded software development revolving around an Arduino. Now, I'm tasked with explaining to the class how the MFRC522 works and where it might be applicable, but before all that, I probably am lacking the basic knowledge before I can proceed with my work.

I have [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnpew.png) the image of the pinout from a MFRC522 and I have the following questions:

- Theres UART, I2C and SPI. Are they all separate communication protocols or are they all involved somehow with each other on this device? If I plan to use only UART for example, is it possible that I just only use the RX and TX?
- Are there restrictions as to which pins on the Arduino or the MFRC522 I could possibly use, depending on the protocol or circumstances? I can see in the datasheet the pins D1 to D7 being referenced, but I cannot find it anywhere on the MFRC522 itself.
- In case they are separate protocols, I would like to know how each protocol is applicable for this specific device? Like a general idea as to why a protocol is suited for a certain every day device we have been using.
- The device itself uses only 3.3V, but is it also 5V resistant? Like, will plugging it into a 5V fry the circuit board or will it work just as fine?

Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at [the datasheet of that chip](https://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MFRC522.pdf):

Paragraph 8.1 says

> The MFRC522 supports direct interfacing of hosts using SPI, I2C-bus or serial UART interfaces. The MFRC522 resets its interface and checks the current host interface type automatically after performing a power-on or hard reset. The MFRC522 identifies the host interface by sensing the logic levels on the control pins after the reset phase. This is done using a combination of fixed pin connections.

But it seems that on **this specific board** the control pins are preconfigured for SPI. But, the [supporting library only supports SPI](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/MFRC522) so I guess that's OK. For other applications the control pins will be connected differently, and the pins will take up an i2c or serial async role. Applications for the other interfaces include microcontrollers without an SPI interface but with an i2c interface, or eg general purpose computers that have easy access to serial async interfaces, like PC's

- the pin names D1-D7 in the datasheet are not related to the Arduino's pins with the same names, that's just a coincidence. If you use the aforementioned library, the Arduino pins to use are documented:

```
 
     * Pin layout should be as follows:
     * Signal     Pin              Pin               Pin
     *            Arduino Uno      Arduino Mega      MFRC522 board
     * ------------------------------------------------------------
     * Reset      9                5                 RST
     * SPI SS     10               53                SDA
     * SPI MOSI   11               51                MOSI
     * SPI MISO   12               50                MISO
     * SPI SCK    13               52                SCK
```

- what the device will tolerate in terms of voltage on its pins is documented in chapter 11. Absolute max on most pins is 4.5 V, so the chance that 5V will fry the component is so high you probably don't want to try.

---

I think [this](http://www.sunrom.com/p/mifare-rfid-readerwriter-1356mhz-rc522) is your board, and luckily they include a schematic on that page:

[image]

Here's it clearly visible that pin 1 is connected to ground, and pin 32 is connected to 3.3V, which shows that it's indeed hardcoded to SPI mode.

Comment: Thanks for helping out again, after helping me provide these informations. :)
As the device is hardcoded to SPI mode, I guess I do not need to worry about the other compatible host interfaces. I understand how Pin 1 being connected to GND would rule out the possibility of I2C mode, but how does EA being connected to 3.3V rule out the possibility that it uses UART communication?

Comment: @Tsubakura the communication mode is decided by the *combination* of pins 1 and 32, and UART needs pins 1 AND 32 tied to 0. That's explained in 8.1.1